# When did the URL JS object show up in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Was recently perusing http://www.chromestatus.com/ and noticed the URL object was `in development` however, a quick text in the console revealed that it has, in fact, dropped.

```
var uri = new URL('../bar/index.html','http://example.com/foo'); //returns an URL object
```

Since I want to use this in extension development (to replace the `a.href` hack) I would like to know which is the minimum version of Chrome I can target?

Comment: `URL` has been around for a long time with [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL).

Comment: Thanks. I was more looking for URL as a parsing mechanism, specifically for converting relative urls to fully qualified ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

using the URL as a constructor for an object that implements the URLUtils properties was included in Chrome 32.